# gradle - how does it decide which jar version to use?

Tags: java, gradle

I've created a one-off of a public domain library to use for testing. I built it and copied it to a server so the rest of my group can use it also. Unfortunately when I run `./gradlew build` it's picking up the original version.

I set the `compile` line in **build.gradle** to have '+' for the version

How does gradle decide which version to include and how would I force it to use my updated copy?

Comment: compile '<group>:<artifact>:<versionID>'. Did you try setting the versionID?

Comment: What exactly did you do? Why don't you use the original version? And if you modified it, did you change the group-id, artifact-id and version?

Comment: I updated some things in the .jar that weren't working properly. If I can get them stable I'll PR it back to the original. The original wasn't using gradle so I build a small framework around it but I guess it isn't setting version information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the original version is 2.0, and your version is 2.1, and the dependency spec refers to "2.0.+" (or some variation of that), it's going to take the FIRST artifact that matches that version expression.  You may think it means to find the "largest", or somehow to know that it should get your version, but that's not what's happening here.

In short, set the dependency to a specific version.

If you have non-standard repositories, read the "Repositories" section of the Gradle User Guide for information on how to configure that: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories .

Comment: My issue is around the fact that gradle isn't designed to pull from a (non-maven)url. What I have for the version is immaterial until I get that part working.

Comment: Gradle was "designed" to pull artifacts from anyplace you want to get them from, as long as you can define the repository properly.  Perhaps if you would show your actual build script?

Comment: Unf the script is a bit convoluted (lots of sub projects and so forth). How would you pull a `compile()` object from a non-maven https source?

Comment: I provided a link into the user guide.  It's best to read it top to bottom if you're starting this journey. There is a PDF version.